Python twitter bot not working, how do I make it use the free access?
Im building a twitter bot and the API isnt working. It seems I have the free version of it and i am getting errors such as
453 - You currently have access to a subset of Twitter API v2 endpoints and limited v1.1 endpoints (e.g. media post, oauth) only. If you need access to this endpoint, you may need a different access level. You can learn more here: https://developer.twitter.com/en/portal/product
My code is below
import tweepy
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import random

import tweepy.errors

auth = tweepy.AppAuthHandler('xxx', 'xxx')
api = tweepy.API(auth)

randomInt = random.randint(0, 416)      # random quote selection

# requesting url

response = requests.get('https://everydaypower.com/famous-movie-quotes/')
if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
else:
    print("request failed")
    print(response.status_code)

pattern = r"^\d+\. (.*)$"

quoteList = []
quote_items = soup.find('div', id='mvp-content-wrap')
for quote_item in quote_items.find_all('p'):  
    text = quote_item.text.strip()

    if re.match(pattern, text):
        match = re.search(pattern, text)  
        quote = match.group(1)  
        quoteList.append(quote)             # adding quotes from url onto list

selected_quote = quoteList[randomInt]       # chosen quote to be posted

try:
    api.update_status(selected_quote)
    print('Tweeted Successfully!')
except tweepy.errors.TweepyException as e:
    print(f'An error occurred: {e}')

I tried changing the error exception handling and nothign happened

What is unclear about the error message you provided? You’re attempting to invoke an operation that is not supported at your current access level. If you want it, follow the link for more information. Can you elaborate on how exactly you arrived at the conclusion changing your exception handling to magically allow you to utilize paid features of the target API without paying for them…?

Furthermore, you’ve included sensitive authentication secrets in the body of your question. While a thoughtful editor has redacted them from your question, they are still visible in plain text in this question’s edit history. You should revoke those credentials immediately before nefarious actors get their hands on them and begin making requests as you.
